# Extract bits and bytes from a CAN Bus message

Tags: c++, can-bus

I have a 8 byte CAN Bus message

```
15 E0 7F 34 17 5C 2 33
```

There is for example MCU_SelfCheckStatus at bit 52 and one bit long.
Or MCU_MotorTemp at bit 47 and 8 bits long.

The endianess is Motorola.
My readers endianess is little endian.

What would be an easy way to get them as a labeled data structure? Like:

```
bool isOk = msg.MCU_SelfCheckStatus;
uint8_t temp = msg.MCU_MotorTemp;
```

I thought about unions but I don't know if they allow such things.

Comment: This is just raw data. If it represents a 32 or 64 bit long, then you must know the _network endianess_ of whatever higher layer protocol this is. Since we don't, we can't answer the question. CAN in particular is quite nasty when it comes to endianess, because identifiers and CRC etc are big endian, then various higher layer protocols use either little or big endian for the payload.

Comment: @Lundin I added that Info to my question. Additionally I'm more concerned how I actually extract those bits and bytes as labeled fields in the first place, rather than getting the endianess correctly by the first shot.

Comment: Motorola = big endian. [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply apply logical AND operation.

```
bool isOk = msg & 0x20'0000'0000'0000;
bool temp = msg & 0x3F'8000'0000'0000;
```

Explanation:
why `&` with `0x20'0000'0000'0000` for MCU_SelfCheckStatus? Well if you flip only the 52th bit of 8byte long type, you will get that number.

why `&` with `0x3F'8000'0000'0000` for MCU_MotorTemp? Similarly, if you flip only the 47th bit and next 8 bits of 8byte long type, you will get that number.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's still perfectly unclear which bit that is bit 52. In addition, 64 bit arithmetic is very inefficient on every single MCU ever made.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with unions:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int MCU_DC_Link_Volt : 16;
        unsigned int MCU_DC_Link_Curr : 16;
        unsigned int MCU_InverterTemp : 8;
        unsigned int MCU_MotorTemp : 8;
        unsigned int MCU_SelfCheckStatus : 1;
        unsigned int MCU_IgnitionSts : 1;
        unsigned int MCU_VCU_InverterCtrlSts : 1;
        unsigned int MCU_2_MessageCounter : 4;
        unsigned int MCU_2_Checksum : 8;
    };
    uint8_t raw[8];
} MCU_2_415;
```

The LSB (dark blue) for the first value is 8
While the MSB (orange) is 7.

[image: Bit Indices]

Comment: This solution seems neat but is actually non-portable. This could be important for future readers. This code could work with some compilers while not working with some others. There are several things which made it non-portable. The first one is the structure alignment and structure padding which are compiler-specific. The structure fields may not be located where it seems to be. The second one is endianess. This code might work on an Intel-formated CAN signal, but it will not work with a Motorola-formated CAN signal. For code portability, bit-shifting & masks are the way to go.